# If we get a timber-framed single-storey extension, can we later (in a few years) add another storey on top?

Tags: timber-framing, extension

We probably can't afford to get 2 storeys built at the moment but don't want to close off that option for future years (when we may want an extra bedroom). We are thinking of a timber-framed extension for environmental reasons: trying to avoid too much concrete. Thanks.

Comment: If you remember Senator Ted Stevens, he got into trouble because of who paid for it, but his solution was to raise his home and build a story under it then lower it down and make it one home.  The place is beautiful.  Have you considered doing that instead?

Answer (score 3):

Can you - yes - with the application of sufficient money, anything is possible.

Will it be cost-effective - probably not. Building, and then destroying a roof is a very expensive proposition. Removing roof framing and replacing it with an additional floor, likewise.

If you wanted to do this in a way that might make fiscal sense, have the frame designed as a two-story frame, but leave the 2nd floor out at first. It will cost somewhat more than a single-story, but it can actually be built out later without costing an absurd amount of money.